# How to use Awk to select a specific paragraph

Tags: git, awk

I got this git command

```
$ git show 71667ee --stat | awk -F'\n$' '{print $1}'
commit 71667eeed3b5ea03bd36ede5935b64dac41c9e22
Author: me <me.fr>
Date:   Sat Mar 2 11:56:32 2024 +0100

    fix reference to more_linux_s... renamed ubuntu.rst

 src/client_specific_setup/rd_setup.rst | 17 +++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
$ git show 71667ee --stat | awk -F'\n$' '{print $3}'
$
```

I would like to get only the files names so the last paragraph, I'm trying with

```
$ git show 71667ee --stat | awk -F'\n$' '{print $3}'
```

with no success.

I expect to get only these lines:

```
 src/client_specific_setup/rd_setup.rst | 17 +++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

Depending on the `git show` output there can be multiples lines so I need to split the above by paragraphe not to take `tail -2` ;)

BTW I found a git way to get the answer

```
$ git diff 71667ee~1..71667ee --stat 
 src/client_specific_setup/rd_setup.rst | 17 +++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
$
```

but I'm still frustrated to not be able to split paragraphs with Awk.

Comment: Why don’t you look to see if there’s some flags you can use?

Comment: Why don't you do `git stat 71667ee^! 71667ee`? Or use `--pretty=format:…` to specify the output format?

Comment: I updated the question in this direction, this remain a awk question

Comment: Awk processes input 1 newline-separated line at a time by default. Given that each record is the text between newlines, you can't find a newline inside a record which is why `-F'\n$'` won't work. If you had just googled the subject line you gave your question, [How to use Awk to select a specific paragraph](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+use+Awk+to+select+a+specific+paragraph), you'd have found the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any `awk` plus `tac`:

```
$ cat file | tac | awk -v RS= 'NR==1{print; exit}' | tac
 src/client_specific_setup/rd_setup.rst | 17 +++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 11 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

Replace `cat file` with your `git` command. If you don't have `tac` you can install it or you may have the same functionality with [`tail -r`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/tail/).

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` you can use an empty row separator, and after processing all paragraphs print the last one:

```
awk -v RS= 'END{print}' file
```

If you don't want to print empty lines when there is no input (thank you [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for the feedback)

```
awk -v RS= '{p=$0} END{if (NR) print p}' file
```

Or with the pipe:

```
git show 71667ee --stat | awk -v RS= 'END{print}' file
```

Comment: An empty `RS` invokes the "paragraph mode": `awk -vRS= 'END{print}'`

Comment: @pmf You are right, that was it thanks! I had seen it in the past but I couldn't remember it.

Comment: fantastic how would we got, not the last paragraph but the one before the last ? e.g. `    fix reference to more_linux_s... renamed ubuntu.rst`

Comment: Use: `awk -v RS= '{ p1=p2; p2=$0 }END{print p1}' inputfile` ?

Comment: I asked a related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78096772/3313834