# how to get in bash a specific paragraph from a stream?

Tags: bash, awk

```
$ cat /tmp/lorem.rst 
Ipsum error 1 dolores repellendus modi sunt deleniti Consectetur molestiae
adipisci sint eius.

Elit eligendi perferendis 2 natus minus reiciendis delectus! Harum dolor nemo
consequatur eligendi et id? Doloremque id aspernatur cupiditate.

Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.

Lorem 4 officia recusandae eius blanditiis quos. Placeat aliquam asperiores
cupiditate esse in magnam. Ex suscipit ab rerum inventore magnam.
$
```

Even without `awk` any bash answer is welcome.

I got from a comment to this question [How to use Awk to select a specific paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78096553/how-to-use-awk-to-select-a-specific-paragraph) a way to get the N-1 one but I did not fully  understood it and I don't see how to request a specific paragraph e.g. the number 2:

```
$ cat /tmp/lorem.rst | awk -v RS= '{ p1=p2; p2=$0 }END{print p1}'
Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.

$
```

Comment: The paragraph starting with `Dolor` is the `3`rd paragraph from your input, not the `2`nd one.

Comment: "I got from a comment to this question...... one but I did not fully understood it"  That code stores the value of `p2` into `p1` and the value of the current paragraph into `p1`, and does does that for every paragraph. So, in the END section, `p1` will have the value of the last-but-one (second-last) paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some examples using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==2' file
Elit eligendi perferendis 2 natus minus reiciendis delectus! Harum dolor nemo
consequatur eligendi et id? Doloremque id aspernatur cupiditate.
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR%2' file
Ipsum error 1 dolores repellendus modi sunt deleniti Consectetur molestiae
adipisci sint eius.

Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!(NR%2)' file
Elit eligendi perferendis 2 natus minus reiciendis delectus! Harum dolor nemo
consequatur eligendi et id? Doloremque id aspernatur cupiditate.

Lorem 4 officia recusandae eius blanditiis quos. Placeat aliquam asperiores
cupiditate esse in magnam. Ex suscipit ab rerum inventore magnam.
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR ~ /^(2|3)$/' file
Elit eligendi perferendis 2 natus minus reiciendis delectus! Harum dolor nemo
consequatur eligendi et id? Doloremque id aspernatur cupiditate.

Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.
```

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '(2 <= NR) && (NR <= 3)' file
Elit eligendi perferendis 2 natus minus reiciendis delectus! Harum dolor nemo
consequatur eligendi et id? Doloremque id aspernatur cupiditate.

Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.
```

`NR` is the `Number of Records` read so far so if you want to print the 2nd record test for `NR==2`, and if you want to print every odd-numbered record then test the result of `NR%2`, etc.

If you want to count N from the end instead of the beginning, you can create a rotating buffer array to hold N paragraphs or you can just reverse the input and output:

```
$ tac file | awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==2' | tac

Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.
```

but that put the ORS before rather than after the record (paragraph) so you'd probably want to make it:

```
$ tac file | awk -v RS= 'NR==2{print ORS $0}' | tac
Dolor 3 maxime deleniti itaque quaerat ea Corporis labore quod inventore deserunt quis
Eum similique magnam illum.
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records for more information on record splitting.